# Set Initial Values to Input Range in Angular

Tags: html, angular

For one of my projects I have implemented an **input range slider** with custom styling. when the component initializes I want to set max price as the default value in the slider. I tried a couple of ways but I couldn't find a solution for that.can someone tells what I am doing wrong.this is stackblitz demo of my [implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-3bcp5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fuser.component.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-3bcp5j

Comment: It looked a bit overcomplicated: Just bind a single formControl on the slider element and use the `setValue` method. You were correctly passing along the data as `Input`s

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper  nothing has changed in above link.i think you forgot to save

Comment: Argh, my wifi, lost all changes :( gimme a sec

Comment: I have to get that value changes as a stream that why used from control then I can `subscribe` to value changes.btw before I post here I tried `setValue()` and `patchValue()` both either of those not worked for me.

Comment: Does this work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-amnhih

Comment: There is some peculiarity in the behavior of the slider though: when using setValue, the value of the FormControl is updated, but the slider isn't being moved.

Comment: thats work like charm.highly appreciated.can you post this as an answer then I can mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I think there is a problem with range element I mange to set the value but it not reflect to the element even it set on the form control it self 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-amnhih

I bound a FormControl to the slider element and moved the initial `setValue` call to below the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create an input property for the value and set the formcontrol and bind this to input elemnt like this 
*component*

```js
  @Input() value:number; // default value

  constructor(){
    this.inputForm = new FormGroup({priceRangeSlider : new FormControl(null)});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.slider.valueChanges.subscribe(values =>{
      this.priceForDisplay = values;
    })

    this.inputForm.get('priceRangeSlider').setValue(this.value); // init value set 
  }
```

*template*

```html
    <div class="slider-container">
      <input
        class="slider"
        type="range"
        formControlName="priceRangeSlider"
        [min]="minPrice"
        [max]="maxPrice"
        step="100"
        [value]="value"
      />
    </div>
```

*app template*

```html
<app-user [minPrice]="1000" [maxPrice]="10000"  [value]="4000"><app-user>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-p97bya)